# Domino/Notes nhttp spikes on JDBC query to Informix

Tags: jdbc, lotus-domino, informix

When connecting to an Informix server via a Bean (or Jar - I've tried both) in an NSF, the nhttp task it spiking and staying spiked. I do not get this problem if the code is run in Eclipse. Here is what I trigger from an XPage (via a managed bean):

```
public void InformixSQLRS() {

    try {
        String url = "jdbc:informix-sqli://IPADDRESSHERE:PORTHERE/db_cra:INFORMIXSERVER=SERVERNAME;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD";

        Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("After getting Driver");
        String selectSQL = "SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM RtCSQsSummary ";
        String whereSQL = "WHERE startdatetime >= TODAY ";
        String orderbySQL = "ORDER BY startdatetime DESC";

        String strsql = selectSQL + orderbySQL;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(strsql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strsql);
        System.out.println("after executeQuery");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int ncols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int i, type;
        String s = null;
        for (i = 1; i < ncols; i++) {
            System.out.println(
                    rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + " " + rsmd.getColumnType(i));
        }

        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (

    SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: failed to connect!");
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {

        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        } 
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        } 
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("Goodbye! (finally)");
    }
    System.out.println("Last call");
}
```

I am on DDE Release 9.0.1FP10 SHF81. I have the Informix JDBC driver jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar. I have tried putting it in the Jars element, and importing to WebContent/WEB_INF/lib. This happens on both a Domino server Release 9.0.1FP9HF63 on Linux 2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64 and my local running Windows 7.

I get this error: Exception in thread "Informix-PreparedStatementCacheCleanupThread". Debugged in DDE and found that  "IfxSqliConnectCleaner-Thread-1" was taking up a lot of CPU. Suspending that thread let the CPU count to return to normal.

The process completes, printing the results, and the strings at the end of finally and the block. Closing the browser does not release nhttp.

This matches samples provided to connect to Informix. I'm not sure what is causing it to spike/peg for Domino. Is there something I can do to get the thread to release?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and consider using try-with-resources, as your code currently 1) fails to close resources when errors occur and 2) closes resources in the wrong order (result set should be closed before statement)

Comment: The IFMXCONNECTION_CLEANER_DELAY_MAXIMUM connection string property controls how often the cleaner thread runs (kind of). I think by default is around 15000 (15 seconds).
Try setting to 300000 (IFMXCONNECTION_CLEANER_DELAY_MAXIMUM=300000) and see if it makes a difference.
Also, better if you get the latest version (4.10.JC10) from the Maven repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc/4.10.10.0

Comment: I know this is a bit of a turn, but I got the OpenNTF Domino API installed on the server, as I found the logs showing "NotesContext not initiated in this thread". ODA seems to handle it better. I'm getting HTTP JVM: Task 'UserOutput' failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader. DOTS is running (which I presume is needed for XOTS). It's on a dev machine, so  all Java permissions are granted. I can't find instructions on how to set up XOTS, and I'd like to confirm them to see if I've missed anything. As I do this, anyone know why I've gota new error